# I cannot @include the views inside Bootstrap's tab in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, tabs, include

I cannot include the views inside Bootstrap's tab.

**base.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout.admin')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#home">Chat</a></li>
            <li><a href="#menu1">Información</a></li>
            <li><a href="#menu2">Envio mensajes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#menu3">Capturar pantalla</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                @include('tab.funciones.chat')
            </div>
            <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
                @include('tab.funciones.informacion')
            </div>
            <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
                @include('tab.funciones.mensajes')
            </div>
            <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
                @include('tab.funciones.pantalla')
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
            $(this).tab('show');
        });
    });
    </script>
@endsection
```

I have a directory called "tab" and inside I have this view and other directory with the views chat, informacion, mensajes and pantalla.

**Thre route**

```
Route::get('/fun', function(){
    return view('tab.base');
});
```

Which is the problem?

Comment: Is your tab folder included in the layout folder or is it on the same level?

Comment: do u write  @yield('content') in admin page?? suppose ur admin.blade.php page is <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
@yield('content')
</body>
</html>

Comment: resources / views/layout/admin.blade.php and base store in resources / views/tab/base.blade.php

Comment: what actually does not show in the page? all of the page or only inside the tabs

Comment: To show if that it shows it to me but only the first one, I cannot do click in other one tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

**Make sure you add libraries on admin**

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
```

**and jquery, bootstrap as well before html closing**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**here is rest**

```
@extends('layout.admin')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Chat</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#menu1" data-toggle="tab"> Información</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#menu3" data-toggle="tab">Envio mensajes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#menu4" data-toggle="tab">Capturar pantalla</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
                        @include('tab.funciones.chat')
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="menu1">
                        @include('tab.funciones.informacion')
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="menu3">
                        @include('tab.funciones.mensajes')
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="menu4">
                        @include('tab.funciones.pantalla')
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@stop
```